# Dynamic selection of x and y component of histogram in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

Based on the filter parameter selection, I need to plot different histogram in Tableau. That is if parameter=1, then (x1,y1) has to be plotted. If parameter=2, then (x2,y2) has to be plotted.

I have created a calculated field for x-axis and y axis. But it is showing error as :"cannot use numerical bin type in case expression".  Calculated field is written as:

X_cal

case [parameter]

when "1" then x1_bins

when "2" then x2_bins

end

Comment: convert the parameter data type as string, and then try

Comment: data type of the parameter is "string" only

Comment: cannot use numerical bin type in case expression ---how can this show then?

Comment: parameter is string, but the x_bins is numerical bin

Comment: I really want to understand the scenario. Are you okay to connect on Google Meet